# How to install an embedded GPS patch antenna

Tags: antenna, gps, enclosure

How should I install an embedded GPS antenna?

Here is the antenna in question:

[the antenna http://www.robotshop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/7/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/e/seeedstudio-embedded-gps-antenna-for-gps-bee.jpg](http://www.robotshop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/7/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/e/seeedstudio-embedded-gps-antenna-for-gps-bee.jpg)
http://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/seeedstudio-embedded-gps-antenna-for-gps-bee.html

It has a 9 cm cable.

My project box (which contains a gsm shield, microcontroller, custom proto circuit board, motor h-bridge, lipo battery, and charging circuit) is an outdoor grey PVC junction box (like the kind used on hot tubs).  It is just big enough to fit all the components inside.

It looks kinda like this, but more of a cube:

[image: my project box]
<sub>(source: [cesco.com](https://www.cesco.com/resources/088700/334850-ProductImageURL.jpg))</sub>

Right now I just have the antenna loosely held in place by the mess of wires, and it is taking about 40 seconds from cold start to establish a fix, which is usually about 30-100 m off.

So, do I need to somehow mount the antenna to the wall of the project box, facing up?  If so, do I just drill out a small hole in the side of the box and epoxy the antenna to the wall such that nub on top is 'looking' through the hole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would secure it flat to the roof of the box.  From [this application note](http://www.taoglas.com/images/product_images/original_images/Internal%20GPS%20Active%20Patch%20Antenna(APN-13-8-002.A).pdf) which is from a typical patch antenna:

> Taoglas internal GPS active patch antennas like all GPS antennas should be 
>   ideally placed with a **line of sight to the sky**. The antenna should be placed 
>   **on the top of the device below the plastic housing**, without metal close to it. 
>   The antenna cable should not be more than 200mm so as to minimize 
>   attenuation to the receiver. The cable should not be bent more than 30 
>   degrees and should be routed away from noisy components such as ICs.

Taping or gluing it to the top of your box, oriented flat to the sky, should give you the best results.  Keep the antenna cable away from other wires if possible.